# ROS: subscribe function does not recognize my callback method

Tags: c++, ros, publish-subscribe

I am receiving this error "error: no matching function for call to `‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [24], int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’`"

This is my call back function in my class BangBangControlUnit

```
// on message reciept: 'current_maintained_temp'
    void current_maintained_temp_callback(const std_msgs::Int32::ConstPtr& msg){
      temp_to_maintain = msg->data;      
    }
```

and this is how I am using subscribe in my main function

```
// subscribe to 'current_maintained_temp'
  ros::Subscriber current_maintained_temp_sub = n.subscribe("current_maintained_temp", 1000, control.current_maintained_temp_callback);
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper signature for creating a subscriber with a class method as callback is as follows:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("my_topic", 1, &Foo::callback, &foo_object);
```

So in your case you should use:

```
current_maintained_temp_sub = n.subscribe("current_maintained_temp", 1000, &BangBangControlUnit::current_maintained_temp_callback, &control);
```

You can read more about publishers and subscribers in C++ [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers).

Comment: Just a small tip: you can easily include the subscriber in the class which the callback function belongs to making things more coherent. Just replace the last argument with the `this` keyword to tell the subscriber that the object is the class it is part of.